# How to add multiple variables in one string (URL)

Tags: scrapy

My spider starts off with the start_urls, being:
`https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL`

Based on a keywords.csv file, located in my resource folder, the keywordsID (number 20035386) will change. Once the number changed, the spider will fetch the data from another product.

I also have a chunk of code which constantly checks the page if `isTruncated = true`, if that's the case, it will change the page number in the URL to +1. The only problem I am having right now, is that I don't know how to set a second *variable* in one string (URL). When `isTruncated = true` the code need to adjust the URL's page number AND keywordsID accordingly. Currently, I only managed to add a variable for the page number.

Currently the chunk of code is:

```
        if data["isTruncated"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'page': next_page, "category": category},
            )
```

However, it should become something like:

```
        if data["isTruncated"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/ {keywordsid} ?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'page': next_page, "category": category},
            )
```

When I run the spider, it will crawl all the pages of the product with keywordsID 20035386, but it will only crawl the first page of all the other products listed in the keywords.csv file.

**FULL CODE**

**./krc/spiders/krc_spider.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from krc.items import KrcItem
import json
import os
import csv
import time
import datetime

class KRCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "krc_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["kaercher.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL']

    def start_requests(self):
        """Read keywords from keywords file amd construct the search URL"""

        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
            for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
                search_text=keyword["keyword"]
                category = keyword["keywordtype"]
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/{0}?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(search_text)
                # The meta is used to send our search text into the parser as metadata
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"search_text": search_text, "category": category}) 

    def parse(self, response):
        category = response.meta["category"]

        current_page = response.meta.get("page", 1)
        next_page = current_page + 1

        #Printing the timestamp when fetching the data, using default timezone from the requesting machine
        ts = time.time()
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

        #Defining the items
        item = KrcItem()
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for company in data.get('products', []):
            item["productid"] = company["id"]
            item["category"] = category
            item["name"] = company["name"]
            item["description"] = company["description"]
            item["price"] = company["priceFormatted"].replace("\u20ac","").strip()
            item["timestamp"] = timestamp
            yield item

        #Checking whether "isTruncated" is true (boolean), if so, next page will be triggered
        if data["isTruncated"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'page': next_page, "category": category},
            )
```

**./krc/resources/keywords.csv**

```
keyword,keywordtype
20035386,Hogedrukreiniger
20035424,Window Vacs
```

**Current Output**

When I run the spider it fetches the data from all the page's of the product with keywordsID 20035386. From all the other products with a different keywordsID, only the data from the first page will be fetched.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Hello @Jairo R. Flores I do not know how to set a second variable in my url string. Right now, I only have a variable which changes the page number (see the very bottom of my ./krc/spiders/krc_spider.py code. The number "20035386" needs to change to the same number as the variable "search_text", which contains the keywords from the keywords.csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `response.meta` for this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    """Read keywords from keywords file amd construct the search URL"""

    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
        for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
            product_id = keyword["keyword"]
            category = keyword["keywordtype"]
            url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/{0}?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(product_id)
            # The meta is used to send our search text into the parser as metadata
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"category": category, "product_id": product_id}) 

def parse(self, response):
    category = response.meta["category"]
    product_id = response.meta["product_id"]

    current_page = response.meta.get("page", 1)
    next_page = current_page + 1

    #Printing the timestamp when fetching the data, using default timezone from the requesting machine
    ts = time.time()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    #Defining the items
    item = KrcItem()
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    for company in data.get('products', []):
        item["productid"] = company["id"]
        item["category"] = category
        item["name"] = company["name"]
        item["description"] = company["description"]
        item["price"] = company["priceFormatted"].replace("\u20ac","").strip()
        item["timestamp"] = timestamp
        yield item

    #Checking whether "isTruncated" is true (boolean), if so, next page will be triggered
    if data["isTruncated"]:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/{product_id}?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page, product_id=product_id),
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={'page': next_page, "category": category, "product_id": product_id},
        )
```

Comment: Hello @gangabass Thank you very much for your solution.. I feel quite dumb right now, because I did exactly the same thing.. But then with "category". But "category" yields the product name, and not the product ID.. Haha! I really appreciate it though!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a nested for when your search_text change.

```
for [first iterating variable] in [outer loop]: # Outer loop
[do something]  # Optional
for [second iterating variable] in [nested loop]:   # Nested loop
    [do something]
```

Checks this out, it might help you.

[For Loops](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-construct-for-loops-in-python-3)

Comment: Hello @Jairo R. Flores. First of all I want to thank you for your input. I see what you mean by implementing a nested for loop, but I am literally breaking my head right here and trying all kinds of things, but I have no idea how it should be done.. I either keep getting the same result, or it only fetches the data from the first pages. I have no clue :/

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the keyword to the url would be the following. It may or may not need + signs before and after search_text, my knowledge is limited.

```
url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/"search_text"?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
```

though I'm not really following what this line is doing, at least the format(search_text) portion of it.

```
url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/{0}?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(search_text)
```